# How can I add a high quality design to my Android application?

Tags: android, interface

I just finished my first professional application for Android. The problem is that the interface looks like a school project. I tried to find profesional templates for the background and enhance buttons and controls, but I can't find anything.

Where I can find stuff like that?

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

http://mobile-patterns.com/

http://www.androidpatterns.com/

After a while you'll find that certain simple visual design changes can add an enormous amount to your app, and I find a good way to do that is to take hints from examples out there of apps that are really good already, but just tweak it to what you need (e.g. colour etc).

Answer (score 1):

It's not really complicated.  Look into the tool Draw 9 Patch.  It allows you to make images for the background with stretching borders.

So you just need to create some simple image with a border of some kind and 9-Patch it. I've tried it and the outcome is pretty good, assuming you can pick some nice colours. http://www.colourlovers.com/ has some nice colour swatches.